# ¿Cómo usar el asp:CustomValidator en VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb

Estoy realizando un formulario en el cual debe registrar, buscar, actualizar y borrar. Pero tengo un problema, en buscar he puesto 3 textbox como requeridos a la hora de registrar, pero para buscar ingreso el dni y me pide que llene esos 3 elementos con lo que sea por el "required=required()". Intente ponerle un customvalidator para eliminar el required  pero no entiendo como llamarlo en la función on click debido a que me pide 2 parámetros.
Aquí esta el código:

```
    Function ValidarPaterno(ByVal source As System.Object, _
    ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) _
    Handles ValPaterno.ServerValidate
    If txtPaterno.Text = "" Then
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
    Return args.IsValid = True
End Function
```

Y el código del onclick:

```
    Protected Sub btnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
    'RequiredFieldValidatorTB.Enabled = txtPaterno.Disabled
    ValidarPaterno()
    Dim ListarCliente
    If txtDNIBuscar.Text = "" Then
        MensajeJavaScript(sender, "Ingrese el N° de Documento a Buscar")
    End If
    Dim objEjecutivosD As New ClaseEjecutivosN
    ListarCliente = objEjecutivosD.Buscar_Dotacion(txtDNIBuscar.Text)
    Try
        MensajeJavaScript(sender, "Busqueda Realizada")
        txtDni.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(objEjecutivosD.Buscar_Dotacion(txtDNIBuscar.Text).Rows(0)(4))
        txtPaterno.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(objEjecutivosD.Buscar_Dotacion(txtDNIBuscar.Text).Rows(0)(5))
        txtMaterno.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(objEjecutivosD.Buscar_Dotacion(txtDNIBuscar.Text).Rows(0)(6))
        txtNombre1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(objEjecutivosD.Buscar_Dotacion(txtDNIBuscar.Text).Rows(0)(7))
        txtNombre2.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(objEjecutivosD.Buscar_Dotacion(txtDNIBuscar.Text).Rows(0)(8))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```